# group update mysql command

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql tables(tests,questions) with the corresponding columns types. The field correct_answer of questions table can hold a value equal to 'yes' or 'no'. When it is 'yes', it is counted as correct. When it is 'no',it is counted as incorrect. The fields correct and incorrect in table tests holds the sum of those counts. I had wanted a single sql command that does the update of the tests table based on the values in questions table. A record is initially inserted in tests table with the counts put to 0 while the table questions is filled up progressively.

**tests**(test_id integer primary key, correct integer, incorrect integer)

**questions**(test_id integer foreign key, question varchar(35), correct_answer varchar(3))

**Test data**

```
tests
10,0,0
11,0,0

questions
10,'textbook','yes'
10,'fire','no'
10,'card','yes'
11,'lamp','yes'
```

After I run the sql command, the tests table must read:

```
10,2,1
11,1,0
```

I tried "update tests set correct=select count(test_id) from questions where correct_answer='oui',incorrect=select count(test_id) from questions where correct_answer='non'" but does not work

Comment: I see you posit a problem, but I don't see you attempt to solve it at all. This site is about helping people who face difficulties while solving problems, not a site to do everything completely instead of you.

Comment: I tried "update tests set correct=select count(test_id) from questions where correct_answer='oui',incorrect=select count(test_id) from questions where correct_answer='non'"
but does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the aggregation inside a subquery and do a join with `tests` table to update the total counts

```
update tests t
join ( select test_id,
              sum(correct_answer='yes') as correctCount, 
              sum(correct_answer='no') as incorrectCount
       from questions 
       group by test_id) aggr
on t.test_id = aggr.test_id
set t.correct = aggr.correctCount,
    t.incorrect = aggr.incorrectCount
```

Comment: Thanks radar. It seems to work but i do not understand your solution. could you explain, please?

Comment: @PaulNgom,  the sub query is doing aggregation of correct, in correct answers for each test , sum and group by are used for this.   then join is done with tests table to update the aggregated count from the subquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
UPDATE tests 
SET 
tests.correct = (
    SELECT count(*) FROM questions WHERE tests.test_id = questions.test_id AND questions.correct_answer = 'yes' GROUP BY test_id
), 
tests.incorrect = (
    SELECT count(*) FROM questions WHERE tests.test_id = questions.test_id AND questions.correct_answer = 'no' GROUP BY test_id
)
```

Comment: it gives me a NULL value in second row of incorrect column which is in tests table where tests_id=11.